Converting UK driving licence to EU
I am a dual UK / Irish citizen.  I currently reside in the UK and my driving licence was issued by the UK.
Through my Irish citizenship, I could live and work in the EU.  For how long could I use my UK licence (as a resident rather than a visitor)?  What is the procedure to acquire an EU licence?  Could I retain my UK licence or easily get it back if I return to the UK?
If the answer varies significantly by country then consider The Netherlands.


For how long could I use my UK licence (as a resident rather than a visitor)?

The rule is usually 12 months after taking residence

However, in the Netherlands, the limit to driving using a foreign, non-EU/EEA, license is 185 days :

Then you can use it up to 185 days after you moved to live in the Netherlands

You need to apply early at your residence municipality :

Please, bring the following

A colour passport photo. View the photo matrix for requirements.
Your foreign driving licence.
Any expired Dutch driving licence if you have one.
Proof of approval (‘Beschikking Bewijsregel’) from the Dutch tax authorities if you are in the Netherlands for work. See If you are
in the Netherlands for work.
A health certificate from the Dutch driving test organisation CBR if you have a driving licence from outside the EU/EFTA. You may
need this certificate for EU/EFTA driving licence, too. Please check
the CBR website.
Complete the application form and pay the fee. These vary by municipality.
Your municipality will forward the application with all documents to us. Only the municipality can submit the application.
Is everything correct? If so, you will receive a letter within 15 working days.
This states that you can collect your Dutch driving licence from the municipality after 5 working days.
If we need more
information, we will send you a letter. This explains what information
we need from you. The exchange will then take longer.
Your driving licence will not be returned to you.



Thanks.  So quite a bit of paper work but no retest.  My licence looks like an EU one but that is only because it has not been renewed since Brexit.

This is entirely dependent on local (national) law. Nicolas's answer is not far off but simplifies things a bit.

For how long could I use my UK licence (as a resident rather than a visitor)?

Typically for 6 to 12 months, in the Netherlands the delay is 185 days. I cannot think of a country where it's longer than 12 months but as I wrote earlier, it's entirely dependent on local (not EU) law and there are 27 different set of laws to consider.
This is 6 to 12 months in a specific country, not the EU as a whole, so that you are still allowed to use your UK licence as a visitor to another EU country, say when going on holiday, even if it's not valid in your country of residence anymore.

What is the procedure to acquire an EU licence?

That is again entirely dependent on local law. You cannot get an “EU licence” as such, only a national licence that happens to be in the community format. It's not even a given that each and every country in the EU would allow you go exchange your UK licence and you typically have a limited time to apply for this exchange. If that period has passed or you fall through the cracks for some other reason, it's entirely possible that the only legal way to obtain a local license is to take a driving test again.
As Nicolas already mentioned the procedure for the Netherlands is detailed on the RDW website. You need to do that quickly after moving but fortunately the Netherlands does recognize British licences so a retest wouldn't be necessary in this case.
Importantly, unlike a proper Dutch licence (obtained on the basis of a test in Netherlands), a Dutch licence obtained on the basis of a licence exchange doesn't have to be recognized by other EU countries, see article 11(6) of directive 2006/126/EC. This can be extremely inconvenient if you move to another country within the EU as you cannot benefit from the more favorable rules covering EU licences but that's the law. In theory, the licence card should bear a code indicating that it was obtained in exchange for a UK licence (something like 70.UK.numberoflicence on the bottom of the front of the licence). In practice, not all countries really mark the licence properly but in my experience the Netherlands does.

Could I retain my UK licence or easily get it back if I return to the UK?

No, retaining your UK licence is explicitly forbidden and you will be required to surrender it to get a Dutch licence. The procedure to get back a UK licence is detailed on gov.uk. As far as I can tell, it's basically like getting a new licence so more paperwork but you should at least avoid having to retake a test.
